# Convergence of $a_n=1+1/5+1/9+\ldots+\frac{1}{4n-3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Show that the sequence $$a_n=1+1/5+1/9+\ldots+\frac{1}{4n-3}$$ does not converge but the sequence $b_n=\frac{a_n}{n}$ converges.

I can show the first part. For the second part, will it be sufficient to just show that $$\lim \frac{a_n}{n}=0?$$

Comment: All you need to show is that $\frac{a_n}{n}$ converges, so it has *some* limit. If you can actually show that $0$ is the limit, you showed convergence as well.

Comment: @Christoph so simply showing that $\lim_{n->\infty}\frac{1}{n}(1+1/5+1/9+\ldots+\frac{1}{4n-3})=0$ should be enough ?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just note that

> $$ a_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{4i-3} \sim \int_{1}^{n+1} \frac{dx}{4x-3}=\dots.  $$

For the other one

> $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_n}{n} \sim \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\int_{1}^{n+1} \frac{dx}{4x-3}}{n},  $$

you can use [L'hopital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule).

Comment: @MohammadKhosravi: Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Apply Cesaro-Stolz's theorem for $x_n = \dfrac{1}{4n-3}$, and note that : $b_n = \dfrac{x_1 + x_2 +...+ x_n}{n}$

Answer (score 0):

An elementary proof: Let $b_n = a_n/n$. Then 
$$
b_{n+1} = \frac{n}{n+1}b_n + \frac{1}{4n+1}.
$$
First prove by induction that $\frac{n+1}{n(4n+1)}< b_n$ and then deduce that $0<b_{n+1}< b_n$. Therefore the sequence is bounded below and decreasing, so it is convergent.

Answer (score 0):

note that $a_{{n}}=\sum _{k=1}^{n}{ \frac{1}{4k-3}}$, then

$\sum _{k=1}^{n}{ \frac{1}{4k-3}}=\frac{1}{4}\sum _{k=1}^{n}{ \frac{1}{k-\frac{3}{4}}}$
$>\frac{1}{4}\sum _{k=1}^{n}{ \frac{1}{k}}$

and the last series is the harmonic series, which does not converge. Therefore $a_{{n}}$ does not converge. Similarily, $b_{{n}}=\frac{1}{4}\sum _{k=1}^{n}{ \frac{1}{n(k-\frac{3}{4})}}$, and

$\frac{1}{4}\sum _{k=1}^{n}{ \frac{1}{n(k-\frac{3}{4})}}<\frac{1}{4}\sum _{k=1}^{n}{ \frac{1}{(k-\frac{3}{4})^2}}=\frac{1}{4}\sum _{k=2}^{n}{ \frac{1}{(k-\frac{3}{4})^2}}+4<\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{k^2}}+4$

and the last series converges. Therefore $b_{{n}}$ also converges.

Comment: It just said that $b_n$ is bounded, How do you deduce that it is convergent?

Comment: $b_{{n}}$ is positive for all $n$, so $b_{{n}}>0$. Together with the fact that $b_{{n}}$ is bounded from above by a positive quantity, we can deduce that it is convergent.

Comment: No! For example if $b_n = 2+(-1)^n$, then $ 1\le b_n\le 3$, it is bounded from above and below, but not convergent!